# Разбор по составу слова ВОРОБЕЙ

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Удивился, когда увидел в словаре, что слово *воробей* состоит лишь из основы и имеет нулевое окончание. Как это объяснить?

Второй вопрос: если *воробей* - корень, то как разобрать по составу слово ВОРОБУШЕК? Если смотреть по аналогии с хлеб - хлебушек, то получается в слове *воробушек* корнем является ВОРОБ. Не сходится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В слове ''воробей'' действительно, основой является все слово. Оно образовалось, по мнению академика Шанского, одного из авторов ''Этимологического словаря русского языка'', при помощи суффикса **-ии (-ей)** от той же основы, что и славянские названия этой птицы типа польского ''wrоbel''.  Славяне издревле так именовали птицу по её чириканию: звукоподражательная основа в словах ''воробей'', ''воробушек'', ''воробка'' та же, что и в слове ''ворковать''. Основой этому глаголу, как и глаголу ''ворчать'', послужило несохранившееся ныне слово ''ворк''. В Толковом словаре Даля синонимами к слову ''воробей'' служат:

> Воробка, воробьиха ж. воробыш или воробышек, кур. воробойка м.<…> Воробьёнок, воробьёныш м. малый воробышек, воробьиный птенец. (Из ''Толкового словаря живого великорусского языка Владимира Даля''.)

В слове же ''воробушек'', согласно 'Морфемно-орфографическому словарю Тихонова, корень вороб/ушек/ышек (косой чертой отделен суффикс).  Суффикс ушк, ышк добавляется к его этимологическому корню.

В  славянских языках известны аналоги этого слова, имеющие один и тот же корень:

> укр. горобець
>
> белор. верабей
>
> болг. врабче, врабец
>
> серб. врабац (так же в сербохорватском)
>
> чеш. vrabec
>
> польск. wróbel

Comment: ворковать идет от задворка. а на задворке воркуют-голуби.  любовь такая--ворковать.

Comment:  petro, будьте добры научно обосновывать ваши ответы. А не высасывать из пальца информацию.

Comment: слова ворк нет в русском, есть Ворка

ворка во́рка "тонкая веревка, вкладываемая в рот норовистой лошади для ее взнуздывания". См. вера́ть, вере́ть, обо́ра; Преобр. 1, 630; Траутман, BSW 352. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

попробуйте связать чириканье и воркование с веревкой и лошадью.  слабо наверное.  зато по-научному можно всякий бред тиражировать из вики.

Comment:  ворковать Искон. Суф. производное от несохранившегося ворк (ср. диал. воркот с суф. от, как грохот, см. ворчать). Ворк < въркъ, образованного посредством суф. -къ от звукоподражательного вър-. Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

Comment:  А в компиляторе от 2050 не то будет.

Comment: Шаинский композитор, а Шанский языковед...

Answer (score 4):

> Удивился, когда увидел в словаре, что
> слово воробей состоит лишь из основы и
> имеет нулевое окончание. Как это
> объяснить?

Объяснить можно **склонением** этого слова.

Воробе[j], воробь[j][а], воробь[j][у], воробь[j][а], воробь[j][ом], (о) воробь[j][э]...

Во всех падежах присутствует звук [j]. В косвенных падежах к этому **j** добавляется окончание, а в  именительном его нет. Потому и считают, что в именительном падеже у этого слова нулевое окончание.

> Второй вопрос: если *воробей* -
> корень...

А это смотря с какой стороны на этого воробья смотреть! Тихонов видит корень **воробей**, а, к примеру, Панов и Текучев ("Школьный грамматико-орфографический словарь русского языка") -- **вороб**, а **ей** считают суффиксом.

Мне больше по душе вторая позиция.

Comment: Слава, все же на мой взгляд, здесь суффикс слился с корнем и вместе с ним образует имя существительное. Т.н. нулевой словообразующий суффикс.

Comment: Да ради бога! Кто-то может считать, что слился, и при образовании от воробья других слов усекать корень.

Кто-то, рассмотрев одкокоренные с воробьём слова (вороб-к-а, вороб-ышек, воробь-их-а, воробь-ин-ый…), выделять в воробье корень "вороб".

Оба подхода ПРАВИЛЬНЫ.

Comment: Эх! Заметил неточность в своём ответе.

Вместо воробь[j][ём] надо было написать воробь[j][ом].

Сейчас поправлю.

Answer (score -2):

Все сходится, название птицы идет от слова хвороба. Напасть такая, зерно стаями поедает. это " хвороба" произошло  от вора-бей.Смысл в хворобе. Головная боль и хворь для тех, кто с зерном дело имеет, склевывают. По английски хвороба-Jubjub bird. Так что слово бей у воробья не зря. Ну, а про непереводимое идиоматическое слово сами догадайтесь...

Слово по составу не разбирается, потому что и ушек, ушка(горбушка), ышка и подобные суффиксы, являются видоизмененным  междометием "ишь как" или "слышь ка"  Слушай ка..

в немецком  Treppenwitz лестница и шутка по корням, лестница дрожит-трепещет, треппен, соответственно и коленки дрожат трепещут, вид(wits) потешный