# Как правильно разобрать по составу слово "соловей"?

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Как правильно разобрать по составу слово "соловей"?
1) Я бы сделала разбор таким:
соловей - изменяемое существительное (кого? соловь-я, кому? соловь-ю), соответственно – ей – окончание;
-солов- выделила бы корнем (и основой), т.к. однокоренное слово -солов ушка.

2) Но есть и другие варианты разбора слова по составу:
а) Панов и Текучев считают, что окончание у данного слова нулевое.
Корнем слова является - "солов-".
Суффикс у слова - "-ей-".
Основа слова - "соловей".

б) У Тихонова соловей — корень,
нет суффикса,
нулевое окончание,
соловей — основа слова.
Или (для начальной школы) допустимы все три варианта? Ученик разобрал как в первом варианте, учитель исправил как в 2(б)

Comment: См. [похожий вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/49038/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%92%d0%9e%d0%a0%d0%9e%d0%91%d0%95%d0%99).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственного «правильного» пути нет. Ваш вариант (1) хоть и не вполне корректен, но может иметь место в тетради ученика начальной школы, и ужасно, если учитель, ничего не объяснив, снижает за это оценку. Остальные два фиксируются словарями, что само по себе делает их «верными».

### Комментарии

1. -ей- считается суффиксом, ср.: грамота — грамот-ей-0, ворожа — ворож-ей-0 и т. п., в словах *воробей, соловей* выделяется он же (этимологически были основы, от которых с помощью суффикса *-ий*, перешедшего впоследствии в *-ей*, и образовались названия птиц). Окончание нулевое. В косвенных падежах от суффикса *-ей* остается лишь йот, который прячется в окончании (вернее, в буквах, которые обозначают йотированные звуки): солов-j-а, солов-j-ами и т. д.
2. а) см. выше.
   б) Тихонов, видимо, считает, что на синхронном уровне исторический суффикс *-ей (-ий)*, выделять не следует.

Comment: Учитель оценку не снизил, но на вопрос ребёнка: "А почему так?", объяснить отказался.

Comment: Прочитала, что в слове соловей раньше выделялся корень солв-, который имел значение «серый, с рыжеватым оттенком». Чудесного певца чащ и лесов называли соловьём по цвету его оперенья.
Подбираем однокоренные слова к слову соловей - 
соловушек, соловушка, соловьиха, соловейка, соловеюшка или соловейчик, соловчик, соловьишка, соловьёнок, соловьёныш, соловьиный.
Получается корень солов-, окончание -ей

Comment: @TatyanaGrytsenko по вашей же логике получается, что и *-ишк*, и *-уш* тоже окончания. К тому же, в слове *солов**ей**ка* присутствует тот же суффикс *-ей*, что и в слове *солов**ей***.

Comment: Как раз то с –ушк- всё гораздо проще. Солов ушк а, солов ушк у, солов ушк е и. т.п., солов- корень (и образовано слово соловей от солв), -ушк- суффикс, -а, -у, -е окончания. Окончание - изменяемая часть слова, которая служит для образования разных форм одного и того же слова, а также для связи слов в словосочетании и предложении: В неизменяемых словах нет окончаний.

Comment: @TatyanaGrytsenko сами же говорите, что слово ОБРАЗОВАНО от прилагательного _*солвъ_. Вы же знаете, что окончание — словоИЗМЕНИТЕЛЬНАЯ, а не словоОБРАЗУЮЩАЯ морфема? По-вашему, окончания могут образовывать слова?